# What is the difference between function test(); and test(); in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$x=5;
function test(){
    echo"x1 is: $x";
}

test();
echo "x2 is: $x"
?>
```

In this Code I've got two different output although the same way in writing ?

Just the only difference in x1 is function test(); while x2 is test(); only without keyword "function" May you explain to me Why I've two different outputs ?

Answer (score 3):

This declares/defines the function `test`:

```
function test(){
    echo"x1 is: $x";
}
```

This calls the function `test`:

```
test();
```

Then in this example the `echo` is happening outside of any function.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a function in the first one.

You are calling the function in the second one and then calling `echo "x2 is: $x"`.